# area won't move down even without margin-top and <br />

Tags: css, position

Im trying to get descriptions next to a 485 wide picture, I did it on my ways, but when trying to add a new line with the same picture and description something like this:

[image: images]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/7395b2748a947cdab0247b485bc391b5.png))</sub>

But when I copy and paste the exact same line of code and add margin-top to that div, or even `<br />` it won't make any space between them, that's how it is looking now:

[image: img2]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/83bd43135137d7e33c9b2074645fe43e.png))</sub>

What is causing that? very interesting..

I am using twitter bootstrap framework.
Code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="works">
  <div class="field1">
     <div class="work1">
        <span class="title-col">Client: <span class="name-col">Joshua</span></span><br />
        <span class="title-col">Description: <span class="name-col">A suavely, asthetic, betting website based <br />off of the widely expanding MOBA game League of Legends.<br />
It was a great honor doing this design, gaming  <br />websites are always fun!</a>
<br />
   <br />
<span class="title-col">Category:</span> <div class="tag_webdesign"></div>
     </div>
         <img class="examplefloat" src="img/p1.png"/>
     </div>
<br />
       <div class="field1">
     <div class="work1">
        <span class="title-col">Client: <span class="name-col">Joshua</span></span><br />
        <span class="title-col">Description: <span class="name-col">A suavely, asthetic, betting website based <br />off of the widely expanding MOBA game League of Legends.<br />
It was a great honor doing this design, gaming  <br />websites are always fun!</a>
<br />
   <br />
<span class="title-col">Category:</span> <div class="tag_webdesign"></div>
     </div>
         <img class="examplefloat" src="img/p1.png"/>
     </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
<br />
</body>
```

CSS

```
.name-col {
color: #d3d3d3;
}

.title-col {
color: #b2b2b2;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 7px;
}


.field2 {
margin-top: 50px;
}

.works {
margin-top: 10%;
}
.examplefloat {
float: left;
border: solid 1px #000;
margin-left: 50px;
}

.tag_webdesign {
  background-image: url("../img/web-design.png");
width: 89px;
height: 37px;
float: left;
}

.work1 {
float: left;
}
```

Live preview:

http://justxp.plutohost.net/themetheory/portfolio.html

What is causing that problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this rule to your CSS

```
.field1 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will clear the floated elements in your `.field1` container and apply a margin of `30px` to its bottom.

Comment: @JosephMarikle sorry, what do you mean? `auto` where?

Comment: @ZoltanToth `overflow:auto` to clear the float.  I thought that was the more common way to do it, but you chose to use `hidden`.  Is there a particular reason?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I see.. However I always thought that the `overflow: hidden` is more common :) Nonetheless the `auto` works just as well

Answer (score 0):

Find the end `</div>` that pairs with the `<div class="works">`

Add above that end `</div>`:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Should look like this.................

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="works">
  <div class="field1">
     <div class="work1">
        <span class="title-col">Client: <span class="name-col">Joshua</span></span><br />
        <span class="title-col">Description: <span class="name-col">A suavely, asthetic, betting website based <br />off of the widely expanding MOBA game League of Legends.<br />
It was a great honor doing this design, gaming  <br />websites are always fun!</a>
<br />
   <br />
<span class="title-col">Category:</span> <div class="tag_webdesign"></div>
     </div>
         <img class="examplefloat" src="img/p1.png"/>
         <div style="clear:both></div> //MY ADDITION
     </div>
<br />
       <div class="field1">
     <div class="work1">
        <span class="title-col">Client: <span class="name-col">Joshua</span></span><br />
        <span class="title-col">Description: <span class="name-col">A suavely, asthetic, betting website based <br />off of the widely expanding MOBA game League of Legends.<br />
It was a great honor doing this design, gaming  <br />websites are always fun!</a>
<br />
   <br />
<span class="title-col">Category:</span> <div class="tag_webdesign"></div>
     </div>
         <img class="examplefloat" src="img/p1.png"/>
         <div style="clear:both></div> //MY ADDITION
     </div>

  </div>
</div>
<br />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a clearfix solution on your .field1 divs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/1778054

In essence, add this to your CSS:

```
/* For modern browsers */
.field1:before,
.field1:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.field1:after {
    clear:both;
}
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.field1 {
    zoom:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the float:left; off the .examplefloat (used on the images) class it will fix the margin issue.